# What's the meaning of "For the stakes were very high"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I would need to understand the following:

> They tried very hard to mislead the interviewer, for the stakes were very high.

What is the meaning of the second clause?

Comment: [Stakes](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake--2). Does this definition answer your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace **for** with **because**. Using **for** instead of **because** or, perhaps, **since** is a bit old-fashioned and formal. However, it might also be the standard idiom in some dialects of English.

**High stakes** is a gambling metaphor which means the gambler is going to win or lose a lot of money in the game.

In an interview with a potential employer, misleading the interviewer may lead to the interviewee's getting the job: if the job's important, then the stakes are high.

In an interview with the police, misleading the interviewer may lead to not being suspected of having committed a crime. One's freedom is at stake, so the stakes are very high.